How do you call an ArrayIterator instance method from within a PHP extension
In SaxonC PHP extension (written in C++) I am writing utility to allow users to write custom functions in their PHP script which will get called in XSLT, XPath or XQuery. I am using the zend framework. In the C++ code given we have an ArrayIterator as a zval object. How can I call the instance methods such as next, current and valid? It should be simple but internally from within a PHP extension but cannot find the right macro to use.
I can create an ArrayIterator using the constructor as follows:
  if (object_init_ex(&retval,spl_ce_ArrayIterator) != SUCCESS) {

 } else {

   zend_call_method_with_1_params(Z_OBJ(retval), 
spl_ce_ArrayIterator, &spl_ce_ArrayIterator->constructor, "__construct", NULL, &arrval);

   if (getenv("SAXONC_DEBUG_FLAG")) {
      std::cerr<<"PHP internal: makePHPValue ArrayIterator called"<< std::endl;
    }

But the same mechanism does not work for next, current and valid.
This question is an similar but different to the question I asked here How do you know you have an ArrayIterator in a PHP extension

Here is the solution to this question:
zval * arrIter_retval;
zend_call_method_with_0_params(Z_OBJ_P(retval), 
spl_ce_ArrayIterator, &spl_ce_ArrayIterator->current, "current", arrIter_retval)


I found that the variable was not initialised properly. Looking at the php source I found that I need to do the following before the zend_call_method_... was called:      zval tmp; if (!arrIter_valid) {ZVAL_UNDEF(&tmp);  arrIter_valid = &tmp;} Love for someone to explain this to me more or point me to some documentation please
